# Working days of month until current date in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, recursive-query

I want to get the number of working days of the month until current date over time in PostgreSQL.

For example, this month until today, working days is 17. How can I obtain this from the query below or a general solution?

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(i, 'YYYY-MM') as year_month,
    i::date as date,
    EXTRACT(DOW FROM i) as number_weekday,
    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM i) IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') 
                  AND i NOT IN ('2018-01-01', '2018-03-30', '2018-04-02', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-10', '2018-05-21', '2018-10-03', '2018-12-25', '2018-12-26',
                                    '2019-01-01', '2019-04-19', '2019-04-22', '2019-05-01', '2019-05-30', '2019-06-10', '2019-10-03', '2019-12-25', '2019-12-26',
                                    '2020-01-01', '2020-04-10', '2020-04-13', '2020-05-01', '2020-05-21', '2020-06-01', '2020-10-03', '2020-12-25', '2020-12-26',
                                    '2021-01-01', '2021-04-02', '2021-04-05', '2021-05-01', '2021-05-13', '2021-05-24', '2021-10-03', '2021-12-25', '2021-12-26')
              THEN 'Working Day' ELSE 'Non Working Day' END as day_type

    FROM 
        generate_series('2017-12-31', '2022-01-01', '1 day'::interval) i
   WHERE 
    i::date < CURRENT_DATE
    ORDER BY 
        date DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general solution, the best is GMB's answer I think.

If you want to do the same thing from your provided query, you can do this :

```
WITH days AS
(
    SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(i, 'YYYY-MM') as year_month,
    i::date as date,
    EXTRACT(DOW FROM i) as number_weekday,
    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM i) IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') 
                  AND i NOT IN ('2018-01-01', '2018-03-30', '2018-04-02', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-10', '2018-05-21', '2018-10-03', '2018-12-25', '2018-12-26',
                                    '2019-01-01', '2019-04-19', '2019-04-22', '2019-05-01', '2019-05-30', '2019-06-10', '2019-10-03', '2019-12-25', '2019-12-26',
                                    '2020-01-01', '2020-04-10', '2020-04-13', '2020-05-01', '2020-05-21', '2020-06-01', '2020-10-03', '2020-12-25', '2020-12-26',
                                    '2021-01-01', '2021-04-02', '2021-04-05', '2021-05-01', '2021-05-13', '2021-05-24', '2021-10-03', '2021-12-25', '2021-12-26')
              THEN 'Working Day' ELSE 'Non Working Day' END as day_type

    FROM 
        generate_series('2017-12-31', '2022-01-01', '1 day'::interval) i
   WHERE 
    i::date <= CURRENT_DATE
    ORDER BY 
        date DESC
)
SELECT year_month, SUM((day_type = 'Working Day'):: int) 
FROM days
WHERE 
     date >= date_trunc('month', now())
GROUP BY year_month;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=134dc34a07d5e65dfefd0a5093684065)

Comment: Heads up for sorting out OP original query!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get the number of working days of the month until current date

Just:

```
select sum( (extract(dow from d) between 1 and 5)::int ) month_working_days_till_date
from generate_series(date_trunc('month', now()) , now(), interval '1 day') x(d)
```

`generate_seires()` produces a series of dates from the beginning of the month until today. Then we do a conditional `sum()` that only counts in working days. Please note that this does not take into account potential holidays (for this, you would need a calendar table).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8fb823092c4280f1e9ac418015ef9c45)**:

```
| month_working_days_till_date |
| ---------------------------: |
|                           17 |
```